# Kendo UI :Invalid Template error on page load

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I'm new to Kendo UI. i'm getting invalid template error on page load. Did anyone came across this situation

It would be great if someone can help!...........................

```
Error:
"Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'<div class="k-group-indicator" data-#=data.ns#field="${data.field}" data-#=data.ns#title="${data.title || ""}" data-#=data.ns#dir="${data.dir || "asc"}"><a href="\#" class="k-link"><span class="k-icon k-i-sort-${(data.dir || "asc") == "asc" ? "asc-sm" : "desc-sm"}" title="(sorted ${(data.dir || "asc") == "asc" ? "ascending": "descending"})"></span>${data.title ? data.title: data.field}</a><a class="k-button k-button-icon k-bare"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a></div>'
```

HTML Page:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="/static/js/example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS File :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var movies = [{
    title: "Star Wars: A New Hope",
    year: 1977
}, {
    title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980
}, {
    title: "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi",
    year: 1983
}];

var localDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: movies
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: movies,
    columns: [{
            field: "title",
            title: "title"
        },
        {
            field: "year",
            title: "year"

        }
    ]
});
```

});

Comment: You're missing something in your post. Running you code in the dojo, it works: https://dojo.telerik.com/UwOdEfIf . Add everything you can to help us help you.

Comment: The css file is missing probably, without the kendo.min.css the grid won‘t be displayed right

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown sorry i missed a comment here. Everything is working fine in my local system but when i deploy this to Azure i'm getting this error

Comment: @StephanT. i tried including the css also but there is no luck

Comment: #update : I found the root cause for this issue. The root cause is due to some content policy of my application. Thanks for all the support

Comment: @Rajeev how did you fix it?